# Eclipse Buildship: composite builds without changing settings.gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

In Eclipse, I have a imported a Gradle project that has a binary (.jar) dependency to a library which is built using a separate Gradle project.

I want to be able to make changes to the library in Eclipse and use the changed code immediately.  This should be possible using the relatively new "Composite Builds" Gradle feature.

I'm using Buildship 2.0.  I've found out that I can do this by changing settings.gradle to specify an included build.  However, I don't want to commit this change to Git (since it breaks the standalone build) and I prefer not to have to keep local changes anyway.

Is there a way to specify the projects to include in the composite build without changing settings.gradle?  In IntelliJ IDEA this is possible simply by right-clicking the project and choosing "Composite Build Configuration"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and have solved it with a small workaround. I don't know if it is acceptable for you because it is unfortunately a change in

```
settings.gradle

rootProject.name = 'root'

if (file('../subA').exists()) {
    includeBuild  '../subA'
}
```

Hint: If your root project is a web app and you want to start it in eclipse(wtp), you have to make sure that your sub projects apply the plugin 'eclipse-wtp'.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for: it will always include the build if the other project dir exists, so can't be changed dynamically for ad hoc composite builds.  A slightly better solution is to check an environment variable, which is what we've implemented for the poor developers who need to use eclipse (I use IntelliJ IDEA ultimate myself).